# How to implement json2csv in Angular 2

Tags: json, csv, angular, typescript

How to implement json2csv in angular 2 using typescript?(https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv). Is there any other better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be based on the original (I haven't checked), but:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-json2csv

The readme says it should be used as a service, but it can also be used as a plain class, eg:

```
let csv = new CSVService();
```

It has its faults though:

If you have an array of objects that are similar, but not all have a value for every single property, the column headers will be missing for those properties.

It doesn't allow you to exclude columns, which may or may not be desired.

**Edit:**

I've come up with an alternative, which accounts for items with more properties than the others. Use or modify as you wish:

```
export class JSONToCSV {

  private AddValue(Row: string, Value: string) {
    let Comma: string = ',';
    if (Row === '')
      Comma = '';
    return Row + Comma + Value;
  }

  private GetHeader(Item: any) {
    let Row: string = '';
    for (var Key in Item) {
      Row = this.AddValue(Row, Key);
    }
    return Row + '\r\n';
  }

  private GetRow(Item: any) {
    let Row: string = '';
    for (var Key in Item) {
      Row = this.AddValue(Row, Item[Key]);
    }
    return Row + '\r\n';
  }

  private GetPropCount(Item: any) {
    return Object.keys(Item).length;
  }

  public Convert(Data: any, Filename: string) {
    let CSV: string = '';
    let ColumnsObject: any = null;
    for (var Item of Data) {
      if ((ColumnsObject == null) || (this.GetPropCount(Item) > this.GetPropCount(ColumnsObject))) {
        ColumnsObject = Item;
      }
      CSV = CSV + this.GetRow(Item);
    }
    CSV = this.GetHeader(ColumnsObject) + CSV;
    let CSVBlob = new Blob([CSV], { type: 'text/csv' });
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(CSVBlob, Filename);
    } else {
      // window.open(URL.createObjectURL(CSVBlob));
      let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(CSVBlob);
      let Anchor: any = document.createElement('a');
      Anchor.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
      document.body.appendChild(Anchor);
      Anchor.href = url;
      Anchor.download = Filename;
      Anchor.click();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dave-notage response works with Chrome, but not with Firefox.

Here is a working implementation:

```html
<a [download]="csvFileName" [href]="getCSVDownloadLink()">CSV export</a>
```

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as json2csv from 'json2csv';

@Component({
  selector: 'csv-download',
  templateUrl: './csv-download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./csv-download.component.scss']
})
export class CsvDownloadComponent {

  public csvFileName = `test.csv`;

  private SOME_DATA: any[] = [{id: 1, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sarah'}];

  constructor(
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) { }

  getCSVDownloadLink() {

    return this.generateCSVDownloadLink({
      filename: this.csvFileName,
      data: this.SOME_DATA,
      columns: [
        'id',
        'name',
      ],
    });
  }
  // you can move this method to a service
  public generateCSVDownloadLink(options: { filename: string, data: any[], columns: string[] }): SafeUrl {
    const fields = options.columns;
    const opts = { fields, output: options.filename };
    const csv = json2csv.parse(options.data, opts);

    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:text/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csv));
  }


}
```